# Wordpress How to begin editing from admin page (please see picture)

Tags: admin

I have searched the internet but I can't seem to find the answer- is my page not set up to be edited online ? or am I missing something. Do I need to download to begin editing?

Picture below I think explains my issue !
Any information would be helpful thank you [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUhYZ.png)

Comment: it looks like you're logged in as a user in a subscriber role, administrators/authors/editors have a full menu. Either that or you have a plugin installed that strips all that out, eitherway there's not enough information here to diagnose just from a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the dashboard for the Subscriber user roles, and it allows only editing of own profile. Editor, author and administrator roles can create/edit posts.

Are you sure you have an account with high enough role to create posts?

Comment: Thank you, how do I get this ? they sent me a message to login so I assumed this is admin, do they need to give me further access ?

Comment: Website administrator has to change your user role to some higher role with the editing capabilities. You can't change that yourself, the administrator has to update your role.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Administration account to edit the site design and other staff.. This is subscriber account

Comment: Thank you, how do I get this ? they sent me a message to login so I assumed this is admin, do they need to give me further access ?

Comment: yes. Isn't this your site ? If not tell them to give you administrator access